# PHP Does Not Seem To Play Nicely With An XML String?

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I am creating an application where a users draws shapes on a canvas and then saves and retrieves them from a database. The saving part works fine, now though, im trying to load this XML content, Thats where the troubles are starting.

Firstly a user has a list of documents they have created, when clicked it loads that document into the applicaiton to do this, i use the following code, firstly a javascript function which takes the ID of the document, then sends it to a PHP script which retrieves that documents data from a database. The PHP script than loads that documents data into a `$_SESSION['data']` variable. Once done, it goes back to the javascript function which redirects the user to application page.

```
function loadDocument(docID){
    $.ajax({
        url: "load_a_document.php",
        type: "POST",     
        data: { 
            documentID: docID,
        }, 
        success: function(data) 
        {
            alert(data); //THIS DISPLAYS THE XML WITH NO PROBLEMS???
            window.location = "application.php";
        }      
    });
};
```

The PHP queries the database and retreives the name and XML content of the document, it then does this:

```
$_SESSION['document_Name'] = $doc_NAME;
$_SESSION['document_XML'] = $doc_DATA;

echo($_SESSION['document_XML']); //this is 'data' on the ajax success call
```

Now when the PHP is finished it echoes the php context, this shows up in the alert box in the success:{} of AJAX with no problems. Now it takes the user to the actual application which begins like so:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$document_Name = $_SESSION['document_Name'];
$document_Data = $_SESSION['document_XML'];
?>
<script>
    alert(" <?php echo $document_Name; ?> "); //WORKS FINE
    alert(" <?php echo $_SESSION['document_Name']; ?> ") //WORKS FINE

    //alert(" <?php echo $document_Data; ?> "); //STOPS THE PAGE LOADING
    //alert(" <?php echo $_SESSION['document_XML']; ?> ") //STOPS THE PAGE LOADING
</script>
```

Fetching the first two items, there are no problems, as soon as XML data is printer then their is a real problem. I dont understand why the `loadDiagram()` can `alert
()` the XML but my application page cannot. Has the data been corrupted somehow?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have quotes in the string that's causing the problem. Try

```
alert(<?php echo json_encode($document_Data) ?>);
```

Comment: +1 Always check if your *generated Javascript source code* is valid and/or makes sense.